# Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am getting an error expected Spy but got undefined in my angular 10 test. I am using Jasmine and Karma. I have mocked the service SpreadsheetService as mockSpreadSheetService. I am calling the its method. I fail to understand why its expecting a spy.

One possible reason i could think of is that mockSpreadSheetService gets created before running the test and we are calling component.ngOnit which possible recreates the component instance. I tried to explicitly create the mockservice after component.ngOnit but it still didnt work.

My question Ideally we should be testing on the mock object. Why is spy needed.

```
expect(mockSpreadSheetService.loadXML).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

TestComponent

```
 let component: SpreadsheetComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SpreadsheetComponent>;
  let mockSpreadSheetService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        declarations: [SpreadsheetComponent],
        providers: [{SpreadsheetService, useFactory: () =>   mockSpreadSheetService.Object}]
      })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {

    mockSpreadSheetService = new Mock<SpreadsheetService>({
      loadXML: () => of(xmlData)
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SpreadsheetComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    //fixture.detectChanges();

  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call loadXML when ngOnInit is called', fakeAsync(() => {
   // spyOn(component.spreadsheetService, 'loadXML');
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    expect(mockSpreadSheetService.loadXML).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```

Main component

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.spreadsheetService.loadXML().subscribe((data) => {
      this.parseXML(data)
        .then((data) => {
          console.log('data is ' , data);
          this.xmlItems = data;
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: You commented out `// spyOn(component.spreadsheetService, 'loadXML');` so no spy is been called but in your test you are using `toHaveBeenCalled()` method. uncomment it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spy is not correctly created.

Here's how it would look:

```
let component: SpreadsheetComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SpreadsheetComponent>;
  let mockSpreadSheetService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockSpreadSheetService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['loadXML']);
    mockSpreadSheetService.loadXML.and.returnValue(of());

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [SpreadsheetComponent],
      providers: { provide: SpreadsheetService, useValue: mockSpreadSheetService }
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SpreadsheetComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call loadXML when ngOnInit is called', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(mockSpreadSheetService.loadXML).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: I have uncommented the spyOn in my code but still get Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.

Comment: Did you spied on `mockSpreadSheetService` or `component.spreadsheetService`? You have to spy on `mockSpreadSheetService` since, you're expecting that to have been called.

Comment: i mocked on mockSpreadSheetService and getting   Error: <spyOn> : loadXML() method does not exist

Comment: it('should call loadXML when ngOnInit is called', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(mockSpreadSheetService, 'loadXML').and.returnValue(of(xmlData));
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    expect(mockSpreadSheetService.loadXML).toHaveBeenCalled();

  }));

Comment: I also tried  spyOn(mockSpreadSheetService, 'loadXML()').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} });

Comment: Okay, I think I see it now. Why do you have two `beforeEach()`, not that it's wrong but you're providing the mockedService before it's created. Try moving the providers after you have created the mocked service.

Comment: i thought so but when i tried  it('should call loadXML when ngOnInit is called', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(mockSpreadSheetService, 'loadXML').and.returnValue(of(xmlData));
    component.ngOnInit();
    mockSpreadSheetService = new Mock<SpreadsheetService>({
      loadXML: () => of(xmlData)
    });
    tick();
    expect(mockSpreadSheetService.loadXML).toHaveBeenCalled();

  }));

Comment: No, you're not doing it right. Let me post the code in the answer.

Comment: @Tom Edited my answer. Can you try that?

Comment: Sure . I have a question. Shouldnt you spyOn mockSpreadSheetService instead of component.spreadsheetService

Comment: @Tom Yes, that's what copy-paste do. Updated.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. still getting  <spyOn> : loadXML() method does not exist

Comment: @Tom Sorry, I didn't notice the way you're mocking the service. You're doing the C# way, that's not how we do it in angular. Update the code. This should work now.

Comment: @Tom Also, I don't think you need `fakeAsync` and `tick`. Since you're spying on the service method, it won't get called truly.

Comment: Now it works but with small change. With the way now it is done, SpOn is no longer needed as i get the message already spied. So commenting out SpyOn makes the test work

Comment: @Tom Interesting!